# python : problem in saving for loop as a variable

Tags: python, pdf

```
full_text = ''

i=0
while i<pdf_reader.getNumPages():
    pageinfo = pdf_reader.getPage(i)
    text += str(pageinfo.extractText())
    print(pageinfo.extractText())
    i = i + 1
```

I am attempting to extract all the text from a PDF file, i am able to extract all the texts by for loop. However, i want to save the for loop as a variable for manipulation. After i saved the for loop as all_results, i simply can't do any action afterward. For instance i try to check the length of the text and the output is 0.

Comment: Is this a direct copy? I see a lot of missing spaces for encapsulation of your loops and if statements.

Comment: Can you edit the post and fix the indentation of the code?

Comment: You can't save a for loop as a variable. If you want to reuse the for loop, you can wrap it in a function and call the function later on

Comment: Are you sure the problem is not due to the indentation of the code?

Comment: @ParamSiddharth: That's probably just an issue of copying the code to Stack Overflow. Hopefully Kenny will [edit] the question to show the right indentation so we can tell where the loop ends. But it's also not very clear what "saving the loop" means. If `all_results` is a string and `i` is an integer, `all_results += i` can't possibly work. I'm not sure what is intended, really. Maybe just make a new `range` object? Or if you want to save the text, append the output of `pageObj.extractText()` to a list?

Comment: Looks like copy paste messed up the indents. First line still has the indentation & he's able to see the data from pdf.

Comment: about the working, using a `stringIO` to buffer all inputs into one single stream and fetching the content at the end would be ideal.

Comment: sorry guys, i am very new in python, so my knowledge is really limited

Comment: what i am trying to do is to save the full text content like the get_page and extract text function in PyPDF2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, you want to merge all the text into a single variable to be used after the loop is done.

Try this code:

```
all_pg_text = ''
all_results = 0
for i in range(0, num_of_pages):
    print("Page Number: " + str(i))
    print("- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -")
    pageObj = pdf_reader.getPage(i)
    pg_text = pageObj.extractText()
    print(pg_text)  # one page
    all_pg_text += pg_text  # add to full text
    print("- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -")
    all_results +=i
pdfFile.close()

print(all_pg_text)\
```

Based on your updated question, this might work:

```
full_text = ''

i=0  
while i < pdf_reader.getNumPages():
    pageinfo = pdf_reader.getPage(i)
    full_text += str(pageinfo.extractText())
    print(pageinfo.extractText())
    i = i + 1  

print(full_text)
```

Comment: yes, thank you very much, that's what i am looking for! sorry for my unclear question

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [PDF Miner](https://github.com/pdfminer/pdfminer.six) package to extract the text from the PDF files. Hereby I have attached a sample code (Tested).

```
from io import StringIO
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage


def convert(fname, pages=None):
    if not pages:
        # To include all pages
        pagenums = set()
    else:
        # We can specify pages by giving an iterable of pagenumbers
        pagenums = set(pages)

    output = StringIO()
    manager = PDFResourceManager()
    converter = TextConverter(manager, output, laparams=LAParams())
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(manager, converter)

    # Input PDF
    infile = open(fname, 'rb')
    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(infile, pagenums):
        interpreter.process_page(page)

    # Close all
    infile.close()
    converter.close()
    txt = output.getvalue()
    output.close()
    return txt


# Usage
text = convert('/home/stark/Desktop/file.pdf')  # Includes all Pages
text = convert('/home/stark/Desktop/file.pdf', pages=[1, 2, 3])  # specify pages here
print(text)
```